# Guake no longer showing desktop when opening

Tags: command-line, guake

It used to show the desktop as a background when  I open it, but for some reason it's just overlying (so the top most window is now the background). Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this?

NOTE: I didn't like setting an image background because I can't specify how the image will be positioned (tiled, streched, centered, zoomed).

Answer (score 2):

I found what it is. It's the `Use compositing` which I have enabled in my desktop settings. When I had that disabled in showed my desktop background now, but applications don't have that transparency in the backgrounds anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the proper way Guake should function. Are you sure it formerly would not show the top-most item and your background instead? There is no setting to change this so that it only shows your background and not the top-most item, but you can suggest it on the website (`guake.org`) or on their Github page (`github.com/Guake/guake`).